# Cannot connect to private testnet with web3.js

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, web3-providers, ipc

I have setup a local private test net and now I want to connect from Node.js to a node in the testned using IPC. I started a node with this command:

```
./geth --identity "5"  --datadir /home/davide/Documents/Ether/5th/ --networkid 4999 --port 30600 --nodiscover --ipcpath /home/davide/Documents/Ether/5th/geth.ipc --shh
```

This is my node.js scrypt

```
const http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var net = require('net');

var Web3 = require('web3');

var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.IpcProvider('/home/davide/Documents/Ether/5th/geth.ipc', net)); 

console.log(web3.version);

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
   res.statusCode = 200;
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
   res.end(web3.version+' '+console.log(web3.currentProvider)+' '+console.log(web3.eth.accounts)+' '+web3.contentProvider);


});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
   console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`+web3.eth.accounts[0]);
});
```

and on the web page I get the following output:

```
1.0.0-beta.33 undefined undefined undefined
```

If I try to connect through `geth attach` everything works but with node.js it doesn't. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are using console.log in the server callback, this will echo in the node console not in your html output.

In web3 v1.0 [`web3.eth.accounts`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#web3-eth-accounts) is an object, not an array like in previous versions. Also web3 v1.0 only support async methods.